# Automapper ProjectTo generating not ReferenceEquals objects for navigation properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I've figured out that ProjectTo producing different objects for navigation properties. I will explain on example.

My model:

```cs
    public class Element 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set;}
    }

    public class CircuitElement
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid ElementId { get; set; }
        public Guid CircuitId { get; set; }
        public Element Element { get; set;}
    }
```

When i'm using just EF.Core request, I'm getting exatly the same Element object in each CircuitElement's navigation property:

```cs
    List<CircuitElement> circuitElements = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<CircuitElement>()
        .GetQuery(csc => csc.CircuitId == circuitId)
        .Include(x => x.Element)
        .ToList();

    var elements = circuitElements.Select(x => x.Element).Where(x => x.Id == GuidConst.AxElement).ToList();
    var comp1 = ReferenceEquals(elements[0], elements[1]); //returns true
    var comp2 = ReferenceEquals(elements[0], elements[2]); //returns true
```

Then I'm adding DTOs, MappingProfile and ProjectTo:

```cs
    public class ElementDto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set;}
    }

    public class CircuitElementDto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid ElementId { get; set; }
        public Guid CircuitId { get; set; }
        public ElementDto Element { get; set;}
    }

    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Element, ElementDto>(MemberList.None);
            CreateMap<ElementDto, Element>(MemberList.None);

            CreateMap<CircuitElement, CircuitElementDto>(MemberList.None);
            CreateMap<CircuitElementDto, CircuitElement>(MemberList.None);
        }
    }

    List<CircuitElementDto> circuitElements = UnitOfWork.GetRepository<CircuitElement>()
        .GetQuery(csc => csc.CircuitId == circuitId)
        .Include(x => x.Element)
        .ProjectTo<CircuitElementDto>(Mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
        .ToList();

    var elements2 = circuitElements.Select(x => x.Element).Where(x => x.Id == GuidConst.AxElement).ToList();
    var comp3 = ReferenceEquals(elements[0], elements[1]); //returns FALSE
    var comp4 = ReferenceEquals(elements[0], elements[2]); //returns FALSE
```

As you see, these Elements are different objects.
Is it possible to configure Automapper, so it will produce one object for all these navigations instead of 3? Or is there some technique to merge them after ToList?

Comment: No, you can use `Map` or post process the result. You don't need the `Include`. Your examples are of course very different :) Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Thank you for advice with execution plan. Now I see, where is the problem. ProjectTo is Select that creating new object for each navigation.

Didn't get about Include. If I will not use it, EF.Core will not retrieve navigations. Or do you mean I need to use JOIN and combine it somehow with Map?

Comment: You don't need `Include` with `ProjectTo`. But with `Map` you do. Why do you need the DTO-s to be the same object instance?

Comment: We need it not really here, I was training on these code. We are drawing graph on canvas, user has ability to move points and all connections of this point should follow it.
We plan to do such object:
```c#
    public class Connection
    {
        public Element StartElement {get;set;}
        public Element EndElement {get;set;}
    }
```
And it is hard to track changes, if all elements different objects, if all objects different. So, we will try to solve this issue with EF or we will change our model a bit. I think, we will have the same problem with JSON Serialize/Desirialize.

Comment: I think the execution plan link no longer works, maybe https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html?highlight=execution%20plan